# Solr REST Delete JSON Logs WARN and Doesn't Delete Document

Tags: json, rest, solr

I am trying to get a simple REST delete by ID using JSON on Solr 4.10.3.

Here is the cURL:

```
curl http://server:9080/solr/oaConfigTest/update -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"delete": {"id":"9e58bcd8"}}]'
```

I get the following response

```
Status: success
Response:
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0
  }
}
```

However, the document is not deleted (even after a commit) and I get a warning in the log as follows:

```
12/14/2015, 2:52:55 PM  WARN    DistributedUpdateProcessor  Unknown operation for the an atomic update,​ operation ignored: id
```

The actual name of the column is uuid, so I also tried the following:

```
curl http://server:9080/solr/oaConfigTest/update -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"delete": {"uuid":"9e58bcd8"}}]'

Status: success
Response:
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0
  }
}

12/14/2015, 3:21:55 PM  WARN    DistributedUpdateProcessor  Unknown operation for the an atomic update,​ operation ignored: uuid
```

Can someone help me with the actual JSON payload to delete by ID (field name UUID)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your json payload starts with `[`, Solr will think that you want to send a list of documents to be inserted/updated.

Your delete request should work if you leave out the starting and ending square brackets:

```
{
  "delete": {
    "id": "9e58bcd8"
  }
}
```

Comment: A small side note, removing the [] from command line curl works nicely.  However, when embedding the JSON payload into Java with an HttpURLConnection, the [] are needed.  Again, thanks for the assistance.